# Talend, Postgres and sequences

Tags: postgresql, jpa, talend

I have a JPA application and associated Postgres schema that was designed with a single sequence table (not a sequence). I am trying to populate several tables using Talend tPostgresqlOutput.  These tables have keys that are sequenced by the JPA application.  I am at a loss to work out how to read a sequence number from the table, update it and then use the sequence number to key a record on an insert with Talend.  I can work it through with a sequence, but this is a table.

Comment: Another good reason not to use workarounds like "sequence tables". It's essentially the same with your other question: use a native Postgres sequence for each table, e.g. implicitly by defining the column as `serial`.

Comment: I am just looking at the mechanism for doing that now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sequence tables are useful if you need gapless ID generation (via row locking). But that's about all they're good for, I agree.

Comment: @CraigRinger at the risk of derailing this question, what use cases require gapless IDs?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The most common one is in some accounting systems where numbers must be contiguous, without skipped values. Cheque numbers, for instance. I don't come across many real world use cases but they do exist.